# How to handle multiple moc on main queue

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'd like to have one moc per entity on the main queue so user can modify many entities in the same time.

Let's say there're 2 entities : "Bag" and "Category", and a bag can have many categories. So while the user modifies/creates a item in Bag when it comes to pick up a categorie the user can as well modifies/creates categories and of course save or cancel changes. So to avoid saving or cancelling changes in "Bag" when the user only saves "Category" I use 2 moc on the same PersistentStore one for "Bag" and a second for "Category" but both init with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

And "strangely" changes aren't properly saved and rollBack() becomes a mess ...

I found nowhere an explanation about using multiple moc on the main queue ...

Any help ?

Thanks a lot !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As much as possible, try to only use a single managed object context. It makes everything a lot simpler.

If you need to use them as a scratch pad (so you can undo), you might want to add a child moc to the first one. Both of these will be using the main queue / thread. Note that you can *not* pass objects between managed object contexts directly.

More details in the *Working with Multiple Contexts* chapter in [our book](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/).